# Demonstrate by definition the following limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Demonstrate by definition the following limit

∀ ε>0 Ǝ M>0 / x>M ,|a_x-L|< ε

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2+4}{(x-1)(x+2)(x-3)} = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2+4}{(x-1)(x+2)(x-3)}$$
We want to prove that 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$
by showing that for all $\epsilon > 0$,  there exists $M > 0\;$such that
$$x > M \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon$$
Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and let  ${\displaystyle{M = \frac{2}{\epsilon}+8}}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&M = \frac{2}{\epsilon}+8\\[4pt]
\implies\;&M-8=\frac{2}{\epsilon}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{2}{M-8}=\epsilon\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then for any $x > M$,
\begin{align*}
|f(x)| &= \left|\frac{x^2+4}{(x-1)(x+2)(x-3)}\right|\\[4pt]
&=\frac{x^2+4}{(x-1)(x+2)(x-3)}&&\text{[since $x > M > 8$]}\\[4pt]
&<\frac{x^2 + 4x + 4}{(x-1)(x+2)(x-3)}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(x+2)^2}{(x-1)(x+2)(x-3)}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{x+2}{(x-1)(x-3)}\\[4pt]
&<\frac{x+2}{(x-3)^2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{x-3}{(x-3)^2}+\frac{5}{(x-3)^2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{5}{(x-3)^2}\\[4pt]
&<\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{x-3}{(x-3)^2}&&\text{[since $x > M > 8 \implies x-3 > 5$]}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{1}{x-3}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2}{x-3}\\[4pt]
&<\frac{2}{x-8}\\[4pt]
&<\frac{2}{M-8}\\[4pt]
&=\epsilon\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. It seemed to me that your exchange reached a conclusion so, in response to a system flag based on the sheer number of comment, I [moved the conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64483/discussion-on-answer-by-quasi-demonstrate-by-definition-the-following-limit).

Comment: No problem. But it did kind of finish, so no need for the chat.

Comment: why (x-1)(x-3)= (x-3)²

Comment: Thar replacement was an _inequality_, not an equality.